# How to set the scanning rectangle dimensions of a camera, rather than determine them automatically based on screen resolution

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

The problem is that in the camera a particular scanning area is there which clamped to the size of the preview frame. This will happen if we try to give some more size to it.

The problem is that I really want to increase the scanning area, thus I try to give something like this in my onResume after `CameraManager.init(getApplication());`:

```
CameraManager.get().setManualFramingRect(getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
```

This however throws a null pointer exception each time although the `CameraManager.get()` is not null neither is the `getHeight` or `getWidth` returning `null`. I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: So... what is null then? Surely you can debug that much so that people will actually help.